# how to overcome missing values when importing date from excel to sas 9.4

Tags: sas

I am trying to import an excel sheet into sas9.4. Interestingly, I can import most of the data without any problem. But for the date, there are lots of random missing values (there is no missing date in my excel file). Can anyone tell me how to improve my code please.

```
proc import out= sheet 
    datafile = 'D:\Date.xlsx'
    dbms = excelcs  replace;
    sheet = "abc" ;
     SCANTEXT=YES;
     USEDATE=YES;
     SCANTIME=NO;
run;
```

all date looks like this:21/06/2010, 22/06/2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your DBMS to XLSX and USEDATE to No. Then you'll import the field as a text field.

You can then use an input() function to create a new date variable.

Not ideal, but easily accomplished.

Comment: I cannot use dbms xlsx for some unkown reason. I change it to excelcs, and it still leads to lots of missing values. I fixed this problem use a very slow and time consuming method. I split the `date` row into day month and year in excel. then read them into sas and cats them together. Please let me know if there is any better solution.

Comment: 9.4 should allow XLSL. Anyways, can try same method with ExcelCS.

Comment: I tried your solution use excelcs. The imported dataset has lots of missing values.

Comment: Were they imported as text or dates?

Comment: unfortunately, numeric.

Comment: 20       USEDATE=NO;
         -------
         180
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85252/discussion-between-reeza-and-fly36).

Answer (score 2):

More than likely, your problem is that the automatic conversion is considering those `mm/dd/yyyy`, but of course they are actually `dd/mm/yyyy`.

One possible solution is to use the `SASDATEFMT` option, documented [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acpcref/63184/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002261342.htm):

```
proc import file="myfile.xlsx" out=dataset dbms=excel replace;
dbdsopts="sasdatefmt=(varname=DDMMYY10.)";
run;
```

That sets the SAS format, but is also alleged by the documentation to affect the informat used to convert it.

It's also possible, though, that your data is actually mixed character/numeric (as it would be if they were entered by hand into excel, in an excel that was expecting mm/dd/yy, and instead were dd/mm/yy).  In that case, the simplest answer is to either change your registry to tell Microsoft to scan the whole column (see [this SAS tech support note for example](http://support.sas.com/kb/35/563.html) ), or to simply convert all of the values to character (or at least the first couple), and then add a `mixed=yes;` line to your proc import statement.

(The registry setting may not have an effect if you're using PC Files Server, which you may be given the `excelcs` dbms above.  In that case, ignore that particular suggestion.)

Comment: Hi Joe, Thanks for your answer. I think you are right. I hand collected this data, excel cannot recognise my format correctly. For some reason, I cannot use dbms=excel (ERROR: Connect: Class not registered ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement). So I cannot use mixed=yes. Could you please teach me what shall I do please.
.